# how to do this on bootstrap

Tags: css, html

I am new in using bootstrap and I want to know how to do this in desktop size:

```
 -----------------------
 |  table1 |  table2   |
 -----------           |
 | table3  |           |
 -----------           |
 |  table4 |           |
 -----------------------
```

Glad if you would help me.

Comment: @Phoebe, share your code not your requirement !

Comment: Why not use a table with a cell with rowspan? Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/9esaxy4q/1/

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
 <table><tr><td>2</td></tr></table>
 <table><tr><td>3</td></tr></table>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
 <table><tr><td>1</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

That worked for me in bootply http://www.bootply.com/new#.

Answer (score 0):

I would use w3.css instead, and divs

Insert the CSS path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
```

```
<div class="w3-half">
    <div>
        My Text
    </div>
    <div>
        My Text
    </div>
    <div>
        My Text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="w3-half">
    My Text
</div>
```

This solution is also responsive on mobile devices
I hope this helps